# Assigning properties to a sprite and to its body

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Is there any difference in behavior between, say, `sprite.setVelocity(100,100)` and `sprite.body.setVelocity(100,100)`? (Assuming the sprite has been added to this.physics.)

Bonus question: what is exactly referenced by `this` in the global Phaser scope? Is there any difference if I assign something to `this.physics` in the global scope, and if I assign it inside an ES5 Phaser class, like a scene?

Comment: Two questions in one question is not a good practice, so I answer the second one, `this` refers to the `game = new Phaser(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    width: 800,
    height: 600,    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    },
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade'
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var cursors, sprite, player;

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('alien', 'sprites/phaser-alien.png');
    this.load.image('alien2', 'sprites/alien2.png');
}

function create ()
{
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(50, 50, 'alien');
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    
    sprite = this.add.sprite(150, 50, 'alien2');
    
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    
}

function update ()
{
  if (cursors.left.isDown)
  {
      //player.setVelocityX(-160);
      sprite.body.setVelocityX(-160);
  }
  else if (cursors.right.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityX(160);
      //sprite.setVelocityX(160);
  }
  else if (cursors.down.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(160);
      //sprite.setVelocityY(160);
  }
  else if (cursors.up.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(-160);
      //sprite.setVelocityY(-160);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.18.1/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for the effort of creating the snippet. I understand that referencing `body` of something that hasn't been added into `physics` throws an error. But I was asking if there is a difference between `sprite.setVelocity` and `sprite.body.setVelocity`. Anyway, I now suppose there isn't, it's just an abbreviation. ... I was also asking if `this.physics` in the global scope references a different entity  than `this.physics` in a scene.

Comment: You have asked what means `this` not `this.physics` is there a confusion here for you ?

Comment: Yes, there is a confusion. Does `this` _in a global scope_ reference something different than _in a scene_?

Comment: Can we move here for more info please https://stackoverflow.com/q/57218858/2107253

Comment: I have been downvotes with the question because I've asked a Question to Answer it like a Q&A to help you remove the confusion so to avoid this problem you can play with `console.log(this.something)` here https://jsfiddle.net/nazimboudeffa/2pcvanm7/ to have an idea of what it refers to